# Update 1 record across 135 tables

Tags: sql-server, dml

There is an application, it maintains delete flag column i.e. if a delete happen the column marked as `1` (in the `deleted` column).

To retrieve the record I must take this `1` to a `NULL`

There are 135 tables having the deleted column, and all of them must be updated based on `ID` column (when it has particular value)

```
( SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'deleted')
```

How can I perform: UPDATE all tables containing the `deleted` column SET `deleted = NULL WHERE ID = 'XXXX'`

Comment: At a first glance, this sounds like a design issue, can't you create a table that holds the IsDeleted value, and link your other tables there? That way you'd only need to change it on spot

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change anything about the app - I barely know how it works myself, it's not my domain - just now that they need help.

Comment: Get a list of the tables, and then use a good text editor to do multi-line pastes of the rest of the DELETE statement.

Comment: You can use a cursor with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query you referenced, providing all the tables you want to apply the UPDATE statement to as a result set, using it in a loop generating dynamic UPDATE SQL statements for sp_execute calls. You'll have to inspect the value of the ID your querying for to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: I would do this during off hours when not in use and changes aren't being made. Then I'd take a backup of the system. Otherwise grabbing the table names and column names, creating some dynamic SQL and a loop or cursor would work here to do that.

Comment: [Here is a way, that doesn't use dynamic SQL, but will return a list of commands you can copy and paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797142/i-have-the-same-column-in-multiple-tables-and-want-to-update-that-column-in-all)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a manual update you could script out the commands you need:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE '+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +
' SET deleted = NULL 
WHERE ID =1;'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'deleted';
```

But, be wary of these `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` dmvs.

Aaron Bertrand lists some good reasons not to use them in [this blogpost](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival) on bad habits:

> ... I feel similarly about the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. Since they are
>   incomplete, aren't being updated for most new features, and Microsoft
>   themselves recommend against them, I find it hard to justify using
>   them in cases where you can (like getting just a list of columns from
>   a table), but then having to use the catalog views when you need
>   information the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views simply don't have (like
>   partitions, or filtered indexes, or INCLUDE columns). Unless you need
>   to write code that will work on multiple RDBMS platforms (in which
>   case you can't use any of the SQL Server-specific features anyway),
>   why not just use the catalog views always?...

So here is another solution using `sys.tables` & `sys.columns`

```
SELECT 'UPDATE '+ QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]))+'.'+QUOTENAME([name]) +
' SET deleted = NULL 
WHERE ID =1;'
FROM   sys.tables t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM 
sys.columns c
WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
AND  c.[name] = 'deleted'
);
```

**Testing**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tableNR1(Id int, deleted bit);
INSERT INTO dbo.tableNR1(id,deleted)
VALUES(1,1);

CREATE TABLE dbo.tableNR135(Id int, deleted bit);
INSERT INTO dbo.tableNR135(id,deleted)
VALUES(1,1);
```

Result for both:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tableNR1] SET deleted = NULL   WHERE ID =1;
UPDATE [dbo].[tableNR135] SET deleted = NULL   WHERE ID =1;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8a04f9ca1107c7098ad9bb8987a948d)